# InputLanguage doesn't work properly

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, input, keyboard, input-language

I would like to automatically change the keyboard layout and I create a simple console application in Visual Basic adding the following:

```
InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = InputLanguage.FromCulture(New CultureInfo("ru"))
```

But when I compile this code it doesn't change the keyboard layout, so it remains what it was before compiling. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried the longer version `Windows.Forms.InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage`?

Comment: @Geshode I just imported the library

Comment: @Geshode Anyway doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

There three ways to change keyboard language:

1. **Using property [`.CurrentInputLanguage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.inputlanguage.currentinputlanguage(v=vs.110).aspx)** (only if input language installed)

   `InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = InputLanguage.FromCulture(New CultureInfo("ru-RU"))`

---

2. **Using property [`.CurrentCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-6)** (only if input language installed)

   ```
   Dim culture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ru-RU")
   Dim lang = InputLanguage.FromCulture(culture)

   If InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages.IndexOf(lang) >= 0 Then
       InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages(InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages.IndexOf(lang))
       System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture
   End If
   ```

---

3. **Using winapi function [`.LoadKeyboardLayout`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646305(VS.85).aspx)** (slowly, works even if input language not installed)

   ```
   <DllImport("user32.dll")>
   Private Shared Function LoadKeyboardLayout(ByVal pwszKLID As String, ByVal Flags As UInteger) As IntPtr
   End Function

   LoadKeyboardLayout("00000419", 1)
   ```

---

**Additional**

For check current culture:

```
InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage.Culture.Name
```

Check is input language installed:

```
InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages.IndexOf(InputLanguage.FromCulture(New CultureInfo("ru-RU"))
```

Switch to next locale identifier (keyboard layout):

```
Declare Function ActivateKeyboardLayout Lib "user32" (ByVal HKL As Integer, ByVal flags As Integer) As Integer 

'switch keyboard layout to next
Sub SwitchKeyboardLayout()
    Dim HKL_NEXT As Integer = 1
    Dim dl As Integer = ActivateKeyboardLayout(HKL_NEXT, 0)
    If dl = 0 Then MsgBox("Unsuccessful!")
End Sub
```

**Additional materials**

- [CultureInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Available Language Packs for Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/available-language-packs-for-windows)

Comment: I used "ru-RU" but it didn't help. The general problem is that you seem to have to be attached to the specific application as there are no 'general' keyboard layout in windows.

Comment: Check this: MsgBox(InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage.Culture.EnglishName);  before and after: InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = InputLanguage.FromCulture(New CultureInfo("ru-RU"))

Comment: Is lang "ru" exists on user lang list (language panel)

Comment: Technically it changes the culture but the keyboard layout itself isn't changed. Yes, 'ru' keyboard does exist in the list

Comment: Please check above^

Comment: Thank you a lot, I'll take a look at this a bit later